# Using ajax to access web from local file

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm a bit new to JQuery and ajax, so i apologize if this is a newbie's question.

I'm trying to use ajax from a local file to access the web (for example, getting a text file).
I'm not using IIS or anything, simple file from my hard drive (and i need it to stay that way).
Checked it on both IE8 and Chrome (version 11.0.696.60).

Here's some javascript to illustrate:

```
// use ajax to load from the web
$("#webText").click(function(){
    $.get("http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_load.txt", function(result){
        alert(result);
});
```

This code is trying to load a text file from the web - the operation fails on both IE and chrome (won't get to get to the success function).
Chrome's notifies in the error console about *"XmlHttpRequest cannot load*  _http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_load.txt: *Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"*

```
// use ajax to load from a local file
$("#localText").click(function(){
    $.get("demo_ajax_load.txt", function(result){
        alert(result);
});
```

This code is trying to load from a local text file.
IE: the operation succeeds.
Chrome: fails with same error as above.

At this point i thought it was impossible to communicate with the web from a local file, but then i came across a similar question: [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Using the examples given there, I tried:

```
// use ajax to load json object from the web
$("#webJSON").click(function(){
    var url = 'http://www.panoramio.com/wapi/data/get_photos?v=1&key=dummykey&tag=test&offset=0&length=20&minx=-30&miny=0&maxx=0&maxy=150';
    $.get(url, function(json) {
        alert(json.photos[1].photoUrl);
    }, "jsonp");
});
```

And this code works great on both browsers. So obviously, it is possible to communicate with a web service from a local file.

Any ideas?

BTW - i'm more interested with the IE aspect of this, Chrome and other browsers are less of an issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused - did you just answer your own question? :-)

Comment: No, what i meant is - if certain requests are possible (like jsonp), are other requests (like for a simple text file) are also possible that way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which applies to all "real" ajax calls (calls actually using `XMLHttpRequest`).

The reason IE works but Firefox and Chrome don't is simple: IE doesn't apply the SOP when the origin is a local file and the resource you're trying to retrieve is on the web. Chrome and Firefox, on the other hand, apply the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) standard from the W3C and so include the relevant "this is my origin, will you let me talk to you?" headers — and w3schools is saying "No, I won't talk to you." ("null" is the "origin" value for the local machine.) The joy of having a choice of browsers is that they can make different design decisions on things like this.

The code you found that works isn't doing a real ajax call, it's doing [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), which doesn't use `XMLHttpRequest` at all and so bypasses the SOP, but only for `GET` operations (not `POST`) and only if the other end supports it. (jQuery's `get` function can do both real ajax calls and JSON-P, the key to what it's doing is the `dataType` parameter, which in the example you showed is "jsonp".)

You may find [this article](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax) useful. It describes using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) (an HTML scraping service from Yahoo) as a cross-domain proxy, since YQL supports JSON-P.

Comment: @Omri: You're welcome! I'm glad that helped. (I've pointed out the YQL thing to at least 4-5 people; you're the first to report back that they've actually used it. Cool.)