# Sending ajax request with a REST works but not with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an ajax call. I used a REST test extension for Chrome called `Postman` [[Link to it]](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en). When I send the call with the extension it works, but when I send it via jQuery it doesn't work and I get as an error message: "error 0".

This is the request that the Postman tool sends to the server:

```
POST /form/front HTTP/1.1
Host: go.com
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "sitename": "AAGx", "zone": 12, "sector": 34, "square": 7}
```

This is my code to send a request to the server:

```
function insert_newform() {
    form_data = {sitename: 'AAGx', zone: 12, sector: 34, square: 7}
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://go.com/form/front', 
            data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
            success: function(result) { alert("good!") },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus) }
    });
}

$("#show").click(function() {
        insert_newform()
    }
    );
```

I am unable to find out what's wrong with my call!

EDIT: go.com is just an example!

EDIT2: I'm going crazy.

Edit3: I updated my code to add JSON.stringify()

**Edit4: when I put the files on the server and run the script it works great and everything is fine! But when I run the files locally on my machine, then the calls don't work and I get that error. I'm really going crazy! I can't figure out what's wrong :(**

**Edit5: maybe this has to do with this thing called CORS? But how does it come that it works from the Chrome Plugin but it doesn't work from my scripts locally?!!**

Comment: What is triggering the Ajax call? Is it cross domain? Is CORS enabled?

Comment: You can not call external URLs with javascript or jQuery on the client side.

Comment: *"You can not call external URLs with javascript or jQuery on the client side."* That is not true. You can when the server allows it.

Comment: Have you tried to send as `jsonp`?

Comment: @Alvaro I was able to do that with REST tool https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

If your `data` property is a JavaScript object, jQuery converts it to form data for transmission.  It's possible that Postman is sending it as an actual string. Try wrapping your `data` in single quotes:

```
data: '{"sitename": "AAGx", "zone": 12, "sector": 34, "square": 7}', ...
```

**Edit**: In response to your edits, I can almost guarantee you it is a CORS, or cross-origin resource sharing, issue.  AJAX and JavaScript in general are subject to various security constraints.  One of the most central security concepts that limits the abilities of JavaScript is the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).  The idea is to prevent XSS ([cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)) attacks.

jQuery's AJAX function [will give an error code of 0 if it experiences CORS issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0).

There's a detailed answer about [how local files are under more strict security constraints here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933834/using-ajax-to-access-web-from-local-file) that explains your situation perfectly.

Your solutions are to send the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header from the server, if you have control of the server.  Otherwise, you can try using JSONP which does not use the `XMLHTTPRequest` object and is not subject to those same security constraints.

Comment: I already wrapped my object with JSON.stringify() but this is not the problem. Because when I run the code on the server everything works fine. But when I run it locally then it fails and I get that error.

Answer (score -1):

The host go.com does not allow [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)/[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) from your domain.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://go.com/form/front. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: go.com is just an example!