# Bad request for POST and no return value for GET using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

I have the code to `post` data to the django server and get data from it using ajax. When I use post method the server responds with `Bad Request: /quizzes/
[29/Apr/2019 18:13:42] "POST /quizzes/ HTTP/1.1" 400 83`
And in the ajax code is not returning any information, not in error nor complete.

When I tried to `get` data from the server, the server says it's okay 
`[29/Apr/2019 18:19:57] "GET /quizzes/ HTTP/1.1" 200 249`
but the code entered the error and complete blocks with error msg ONLY "Error with status: error"

Another problem is when the request end, my firefox reloads the page and I don't know why

So anyone can suggest a solution to these problems?!

This is my  Ajax code for `post` method, which not giving me any response 
And the server is expecting to recieve json object in this format

```
{
'title': "superheroes java",
'pass_score': 1,
'num_of_questions': 3,
'expected_duration': 10,
'skill_type': {"name": "java"},
}
```

Here's how I format and send it

```
  $("#add-quiz").click(function () {
        quizData = {
            title: $("#quizTitle").val(),
            pass_score: Number($("#quizPassScore").val()),
            num_of_questions: Number($("#quizNumQuestions").val()),
            expected_duration: Number($("#quizDuration").val()),
            skill_type: {name: $("#quizSkillType").val()}
        };
        response = ""
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/quizzes/",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            data: quizData,
            success: function () {
               response = "success";
            }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }, complete: function (request, status) {
                alert("Error with status: " + status);
            }
        });
        alert(response);
    });
```

And this is `get` method which says `Error with status: error`

```
 response = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/quizzes/",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                response = data;
            }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Status: " + textStatus + "Error: " + errorThrown);

            }, complete: function (request, status) {
                console.log("Error with status: " + status);
            }
        });
        alert(response);
```

I'm just using `respone` for further testing

Comment: Sounds like the error is occurring on the server side (i.e., Django). It would be better if you tagged this with `[django]` and provided the code for the server side method.

Comment: I think you are sending the object but not a JSON. Can you try using JSON.stringify(quizData)?

Comment: @J.Nicastro I added it, but it gives me an error, Error with status: error!!

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just don't think as the server side is tested and doing the right jop using tools like postman

Comment: @shroukmansour usually bad request means you are not structuring your request correctly, You might be missing a header or the body is not as expected

Comment: @shroukmansour can you log the request you are sending?

Comment: @shroukmansour also if you can provide the documentation of the endpoint, do so.

Comment: @J.Nicastro sorry but what do you mean by logging it?

Comment: @J.Nicastro I already have written what the endpoint is expecting to recieve

Comment: var request = $.ajax(...);
console.log(request);

Comment: Seems that there should be a front controller that you need to hit first. Such as `http://127.0.0.1:8001/API/quizzes/` where "quizzes" is the ROUTE.

Comment: @EternalHour No, I don't need as it works correctly using REST client app

Comment: After trying a lot of posible solutions. It seems it's a CORS problem. Solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810559/sending-ajax-request-with-a-rest-works-but-not-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that cross-origin resource sharing was disabled. We were able to solve it adding the needed configurations to the server to allow them.

The server used DJANGO so the steps we followed were the ones on the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework)